# Android image fullscreen

Tags: android

i write this XML code for my maiActivity:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i want when the form start my activity create full screen and image back ground fill or fit the activity.

Comment: And what is happening right now? What is the issue?

Comment: @joao2fast4u now my image not fit to my activity

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in tow ways:

**1- Pragmatically**

```
public class YoutActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**2- XML:** 
you can set it up in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".YoutActivity "
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

that will let also the image full the screen as u set the bound

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get image as your background you don't need to use Imageview.

Use  android:background="@drawable/back" in relative layout declaration ;)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the layout to FrameLayout and add these attributes to the ImageView:

```
android:src="@drawable/your_image"
android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
```

Comment: but i want use relative layout,in relative layout no solution this?

Comment: then add this to the RelativeLayout: android:background="@drawable/your_image"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="com.smbds.app.activities.SplashScreenActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_branding_splashscreen"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    resources = getResources();
```