# White padding/border

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed my app on a device for the first time. It worked great on the emulator but it now has this white padding on the edges which affects the locations of the transparent buttons (See screenshot). I am wondering if there is a way to force the whole image to take up the full screen and remove the white on the sides. Please let me know your best solutions. [image: This is the image]

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".firstroom">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/firstroom" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please include your XML code of the ImageView/View you've used to render this image. So that one can suggest/fix attributes. If you did not use XML, then put the portion of java.

Comment: Hi, I have added the XML code. This is the same across many activities so hoping there is a simple fix. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android image fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472433/android-image-fullscreen)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` or `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your ImageView.

I woulld also recommend you to go through this link: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "scaleType" attribute in the tag to **ImageView**

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

There are some other other types also . Shown in image below
[image]

Comment: This is exactly the same as the first post. There was absolutely no need to post another one especially when you didn't add any other information.

Comment: I see that answer after posting my answer. I was taking screen shot and editing that in paint. Anyhow i think you got your answer

Comment: @MuhammadFarhanArif Even when you're writing your response, it shows you when there is an answer. You should've checked it before you post it.

Comment: Yeah i noticed that answer after posting my answer. I also attached image with showing other attributes and i think there should not be any issue about it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the attribute `android:scaleType`.

If you want to keep the aspect ratio unchanged, then you have to use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`, this will center your image to the imageview and scale it keeping the aspect ratio. So it might crop either some portions of width or height if required.

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/firstroom" />
```

If you do not want to keep the aspect ratio, then you have to use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`, this will scale both height and width to fill your image to the imageview. As a result your image might be stretched horizontally or vertically.

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/firstroom" />
```

For more info, see [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType).